# count if a row value is within a dynamic range?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am after doing a COUNTIFS in python. I need to check each row ± 250 with other rows and if this row is between that range then count 1, then next row, .. and do the same thing. and if there are any, put the total number, else put 1. Here's the code in excel: COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,E:E,">="&E2-$G$2,E:E,"<="&E2+$G$2)

[image]

Here's the code, but it's not doing countifs.

```
import arcpy
fc = "feature_class"
counter = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,("Mean_m","Count")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] >= row[0]-250 and row[0] <= row[0]+250:
            counter += 1
            row[1] = counter
        else:
            counter = 1
            row[1] = counter
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor you don't need `setValue` - just do `row[1] = counter`

Comment: lets say the value of row[0] is 500.  Your if statement is saying "if 500 is greater than or equal to 250 and 500 is less than or equal to 750" - it'll always return True.

Comment: Your updateRow line should be `cursor.updateRow(row)`.  And since you're using `with` you don't need to `del row, rows` as with drops those once complete.

Comment: @Midavalo is spot on with his remarks. The most important one is that your test will always be true. Are you comparing with the mean value of ALL rows or with a value stored in another field of the same row.

Comment: Thanks Midavalo. You are right. I got it running. However, the result is not what I want. I reckon the logic of the code is not right. I am after doing a COUNTIFS in python. I need to check each row ± 250 with other rows and if this row is between that range then count 1, then next row, .. and do the same thing. and if there are any, put the total number, else put 1.

Comment: @Matt you should [edit] your question and include all the extra detail to make it clear what you are asking, and also update any code that is now working

Comment: Your del statement is not needed because you are using with when creating your cursor.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just edited my question with more details. I hope that clarifies what I am after. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You'll need a dubble loop for this task, either 2 cursors or one cursor  + one selection.

Comment: @Matt I'm not familiar with COUNTIFS - I think you're saying you want to count the number of times the value in `Mean_m` is within 250 of each other value of `Mean_m` in your table?

Comment: @Midavalo yes, that's right.

Comment: @radouxju thanks, you mean one cursor for "Main" and one for "Mean_m"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're after, I think something like this should work:

```
import arcpy
fc = "feature_class"

fields = ["Mean_m","Count"]

meanVals = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        meanVals.append(row[0])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        counter = 0
        for mean in meanVals:
            if row[0] >= mean -250 and row[0] <= mean+250:
                counter += 1
        row[1] = counter
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

SearchCursor creates a list of all the values in `Mean_m`, and then the UpdateCursor loops through this list and counts how many times your current row's `Mean_m` is within ±250 in the list.  It then writes that count to `Count` for the current row.  No need to use an `else` as it will always find at least one instance (the current row).

You might need to include a check or workaround for Null values if they exist.

Comment: +1 : it seems to be what OP is looking for. Note that you could use row[1]= sum(1 for x in meanVals if abs(row[0]-x) <=250 )